# Magento 2 Configurable Products Cannot Be Built From Attribute Set

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

In the previous version of Magento, it was possible to create a configurable product from an attribute set.  Why is it that when I create a new configurable product, the magento manual says that I can choose an attribute set, but the admin pages block that option and do not allow me to select an attribute set?

Answer (score 1):

This is a confirmed bug with a workaround.

But I am not sure if creating a simple product with configurable attributes is the same thing.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2567